# SQL server error: Must declare the scalar variable "@lastrow"

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, declare

I have adapted a query found online to bulk import CSV files into SQL server. However, my CSVs have a spare line feed at the bottom so I've added a counter for the number of rows in the file and then set the LASTROW parameter in the BULK INSERT.

However, because I'm looping the BULK INSERT I need to pass the filename to the row counter. But I'm getting the error "Must declare the scalar variable "@lastrow"" when @filllastrow executes. Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Rob

```
        declare @filename varchar(255),
        @path     varchar(255),
        @sql      varchar(8000),
        @filllastrow      varchar(8000),
        @cmd      varchar(1000)

declare c1 cursor for SELECT WHICHPATH,WHICHFILE FROM ALLFILENAMES where WHICHFILE like '%.csv%'
open c1
fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
While @@fetch_status <> -1
 begin
  declare @lastrow varchar(10)
  set  @filllastrow = 'set @lastrow = convert(varchar(10),(SELECT count(*) FROM OPENROWSET( BULK '''+ @path + @filename+''', FORMATFILE = ''E:\ereferrals\MyFormat_Counting.fmt'', MAXERRORS=10) AS a ) - 1)'
  print @filllastrow
  exec (@filllastrow)

 set @sql = 'BULK INSERT eref FROM ''' + @path + @filename + ''' '
       + '     WITH ( 
               FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
               ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0A'', 
               FIRSTROW = 2 ,
               LASTROW = '+convert(varchar,@lastrow)+',
               ERRORFILE = ''e:\ereferrals\probs.log''
            ) '
print @sql
EXECUTE @sql
fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
end
close c1
deallocate c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_executesql` and define the `@lastrow` parameter as an output parameter.

Try something like this...

```
declare @filename       nvarchar(255)
       ,@path           nvarchar(255)
       ,@sql            nvarchar(MAX)  --<-- Correct datatype
       ,@filllastrow    nvarchar(MAX)  --<-- Correct datatype
       ,@cmd            nvarchar(1000)


declare c1 cursor for 
SELECT WHICHPATH , WHICHFILE 
FROM ALLFILENAMES 
where WHICHFILE like '%.csv%'

open c1

fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename


While @@fetch_status <> -1
 begin
  declare @lastrow  INT;

  set  @filllastrow = 'SELECT @lastrow = convert(varchar(10),  ISNULL(count(*),2) -1)
                       FROM OPENROWSET( BULK '''+ @path + @filename+'''
                                      , FORMATFILE = ''E:\ereferrals\MyFormat_Counting.fmt''
                                      , MAXERRORS=10) AS a )'


     Exec sp_executesql @filllastrow
                       ,N'@lastrow INT OUTPUT'   --<-- Output parameter
                       ,@lastrow OUTPUT                                 

 set @sql = 'BULK INSERT eref FROM ''' + @path + @filename + ''' '
       + '     WITH ( 
               FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
               ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0A'', 
               FIRSTROW = 2 ,
               LASTROW = @lastrow,   
               ERRORFILE = ''e:\ereferrals\probs.log''
            ) '

   Exec sp_executesql @sql
                     ,N'@lastrow INT'
                     ,@lastrow

fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
end
close c1
deallocate c1
```

Comment: Thanks. I removed the spare bracket after "MAXERRORS=10) as a" and it then gives the error 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '@lastrow'.

Answer (score 0):

Put 'declare @lastrow int' in the @sql string, remove type conversions and run both sql statements together to keep @lastrow current. Run BULK INSERT in an EXEC function to pass it the parameter. @Filllastrow not needed:

```
declare @filename varchar(255),
        @path     varchar(255),
        @sql      varchar(8000),
        @cmd      varchar(1000)

declare c1 cursor for SELECT WHICHPATH,WHICHFILE FROM ALLFILENAMES
                        where WHICHFILE like '%.csv%'
open c1
fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
While @@fetch_status <> -1
 begin
  set  @sql = ' declare @lastrow as int set @lastrow =
       (SELECT count(*) 
       FROM OPENROWSET( BULK '''+ @path + @filename+''', FORMATFILE =
       ''E:\ereferrals\MyFormat_Counting.fmt'', MAXERRORS=10) AS a ) - 1 
       EXEC(''BULK INSERT eref FROM ''''' + @path + @filename + ''''' '
       + '     WITH ( 
               FIELDTERMINATOR = '''','''', 
               ROWTERMINATOR = ''''0x0A'''', 
               FIRSTROW = 2 ,
               LASTROW = '' + @lastrow + '',
               ERRORFILE = ''''e:\ereferrals\probs.log''''
            ) '
print @sql
EXECUTE @sql
fetch next from c1 into @path,@filename
end
close c1
deallocate c1
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and get and error message that 'declare @lastrow .... )' is not a valid identifier.
I think the problem is that bulk insert can't accept a variable as the LASTROW parameter.

Comment: @RobShaw_UK I updated to declare lastrow as an integer.--Just updated it  again to correct typo.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error. If I run the text from the print @sql on it's own I get "Incorrect syntax near '@lastrow'."

Comment: @RobShaw_UK BULK INSERT couldn't be passed a parameter, so I've amended the code to run it dynamically.